# MYSQL performing tangent query from other table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

```
where meetingID = [[WHERE IT MATCHES]] (select meetingID from meeting where categoryID = '1')
```

I'm not quite sure what to put here to join these two together?

Comment: what is this `[[WHERE IT MATCHES]]`? maybe you can explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if a category can have multiple `meetingID`, better use `IN` than `=` so it will not generate and error,

```
SELECT ...
FROM ....
where meetingID IN (select meetingID 
                    from meeting 
                     where categoryID = '1')
```

another way is to `JOIN` them, eg.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM   tableName a
       INNER JOIN meeting b
           ON a.meetingID = b.meetingID 
WHERE  b.categoryID  = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **JOIN** it will improve perfomance.

```
SELECT ... 
FROM tablea a 
INNER JOIN meeting m ON a.meetingID = m.meetingID AND m.categoryID = '1'
```

**OR**

```
SELECT ... 
FROM tablea a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT meetingID 
            FROM meeting 
            WHERE categoryID = '1'
          ) b ON a.meetingID = b.meetingID;
```

Check this link [**MySQL Optimizing Subqueries**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimizing-subqueries.html)